# Function returning function and no reference

Tags: javascript, function

My question is about  this function:

```js
    function d() {
       function e() {
        alert('E');
       }
       return e;
    }
    d()();//alerts 'E'
```

When function **d** is called  first time function **e** is returned, however, nothing holds reference to the returned  value( function **e**  in this case), and this returned value should be lost. So, how does this **d()()** work ? It's not a closure according to my understanding. Thank you !

Comment: In Assembly (low level programming) there is the so called "accumulator" register, which is a very special register inside of the processor that stores the input and output of every operation. To do addition for example, you'd load a value into the accumulator, add another one to it, and then load the result off the accumulator. Todays programming languages are still influenced by that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call to d (which is `d()` in that last line) returns `e`, and then the last `()` immediately calls that function.

Consider

```
function n() { return 5; }

console.log(n() + 1); // 6
```

Nothing holds the return value from the call to `n()`, and yet the return value can be used in the addition operation.  The return value from the call to `d()` can similarly be used as a reference to a function in a function call expression, which is exactly what happens in your code.

To put it another way, `d()` returns a reference to a function (`e`). In order to call a function, all you need is a reference to a function taken from *somewhere*, and a parenthesized argument list. That's what `d()()` gives you.

Comment: An even more basic example would be an IIFE.

Comment: @Taplar sure; I just figured simple arithmetic might be a little easier to swallow

Comment: Yeah, not to be distracting.  Just thinking of other common examples.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a named reference to a function in order to use it. You can apply an operator to the result of any expression in place, and the `()` function call is just another operator.

So it's little different from performing addition on the result of a function call.

```js
function returnTwo() {
  return 2;
}

console.log(returnTwo() + 40);
```

Here we don't store the result of `returnTwo()`, but we can still use it as the left operand of the `+` operator. So with the function call in your example, you're doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
function d() {
   function e() {
    alert('E');
   }
   return e;
}
d()();
//alerts 'E'
```

It doesn't need a reference because it is explicitly transformed into the returned value. Unless stored, the result of a JavaScript Expression( a sequence of interpreted variables, functions, and/or operations that returns a value ) will be fully evaluated and then removed from memory. The key is that it has to be `fully evaluated`. You can almost think of functional execution as horizontal Russian Nesting Dolls. The JavaScript expression is:

```
d()();
```

So it begins left-to-right with:

```
d()
```

which is executed and returns:

```
function e() { ... }
```

which turns the line into:

```
function e() { ... }()
```

which is then executed, alerts, and returns:

```
//nothing
```

The full Expression is completed. There is nothing left for it to do. The reference isn't stored anywhere and immediately after this expression is resolved everything that was returned from its evaluations is thrown away.